# Adding on and off state in a 555 timer clock circuit

Tags: clock, 555, timer, switching, breadboard

I'm making a clock signal for my circuits, and I'm utilizing the 555 timer for this. I made this circuit below which outputs a clock signal. And now I'm trying to figure out how can I add on and off state on it.

I want the clock turn on when a constant high input is in and turns off when it is low (kind of like a switch).

Below is the schematic I made.

[image]

Comment: So you want three states, always On, always Off, Oscillating. One logic input signal can't select 3 states. Rethink this.

Comment: @Mattman944 no i want two state, on and off state. I want to control the timer based on the input.

Comment: The 200Ω/10μF timing pair is an interesting choice. Is there a reason you chose such a large capacitor and such a small resistor?

Comment: @vir i mostly learned this circuit in videos and scouring similar circuits in the internet. The 10uF was a default value in the simulator i used and the 200 ohm resistor was just me picking a value that makes the timer close to a 1 second interval. I do want to learn if using those types is recommended or not. Is it price wise for the capacitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically i want the clock turn on when a constant high input is in and turns off when the it is low (kinda like a switch)..

Use \RST pin (pin #4).

It's an active-low input so when it's tied to ground the 555 stops (i.e. output becomes zero). And, when it's high i.e. tied to VDD just like in your schematic the 555 runs (generates clock).

Check the datasheet of the particular device you are using (or about to use) for the correct voltage levels of the \RST pin.

PS: The 10u cap across the output may filter out the clock signal. It also loads the output. Remove it, or at least connect across the supply input (i.e. across VDD and GND) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Feed your control signal to the reset pin (assuming the control signal is 0 V to +5 V).

You don't need that 10 uF cap connected to the output.

Obviously you need to disconnect the reset pin from Vcc first.